# Using "convert"-command to handle image processing before output to browser

Tags: php, imagemagick-convert

I have a problem with the ImageIck PHP CLASS. My Provider (1und1.de) only allows to edit images through the convert-CMD by ImageIck. I have a script which i used on another server with a different provider, who allows to install the ImageIck CLASS.

This is the script:

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=".(60 * 60 * 24 * 7).", pre-check=".(60 * 60 * 24 * 7)); 
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime(" 2 day")));

$valid_size = array('xx','sm','xs'); //XX = 1440px * 960px //  SM = 

$img = $_GET['img'];
if(!empty($_GET['output-quality'])) $img_quality = $_GET['output-quality']; else $img_quality = NULL;
if(!empty($_GET['output-size']) && in_array($_GET['output-size'],$valid_size)) $img_size = $_GET['output-size']; else $img_size = NULL;

$img_arr    = explode('.',$img);
$img_type   = $img_arr[1];
$img_path   = '../'.$img;

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && (strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == filemtime($img_path))) {

  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($img_path)).' GMT', true, 304);
  exit;
}

$im = new Imagick($img_path);
if(!is_null($img_quality)) $im -> setImageCompressionQuality($img_quality);
if(!is_null($img_size)) {

    switch($img_size) {

        case 'xx' : 

            $w = 1440;
            $h = 940;
        break;
        case 'sm' : 

            $w = 300;
            $h = 200;
        break;      
        case 'xs' : 

            $w = 150;
            $h = 150;
        break;      
    }

    $dim = $im -> getImageGeometry();
    $wDim = $dim['width'];
    $hDim = $dim['height'];

    if($wDim >= 150 || $hDim >= 150) {

        if($wDim >= $hDim) {

            $o_scale = $wDim / $hDim;
            $n_scale = $w / $h;

            if($n_scale >= $o_scale) {

                $im -> scaleImage($w,0);
            } else $im -> scaleImage(0,$h);
        } else {

            $o_scale = $hDim / $wDim;
            $n_scale = $w / $h;

            if($n_scale >= $o_scale) {

                $im -> scaleImage($w,0);
            } else $im -> scaleImage($w,0);
        } 

        $dim = $im -> getImageGeometry();

        $wDim = $dim['width'];
        $hDim = $dim['height'];

        $wTemp = ($wDim - $w) / 2;
        $hTemp = ($hDim - $h) / 2;

        $im -> cropImage($w,$h,$wTemp,$hTemp);
    }
}
header('Content-type: image/'.$im -> getImageFormat());
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$img.'"');

echo $im;
```

This works fine for me with the ImageIck CLASS, but now i have to handle this processing without the ImageIck CLASS just with the convert-CMD.
I don't know how to cope with this Command Line Tool...

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation that explains how to do it is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).  Did you have a specific question about that?

Comment: Unfortunately the syntax is totally different. Your best bet is just to ask your provider to install php5-imagick and hope that they will do it for you, or maybe even think of switching to another provider that has it already.

Comment: "Did you have a specific question about that?" - Yes, my problem is, that i don't know how to output my image with the convert cmd - like i have done it before

Comment: Don't forget to ping people with an @ before their name (like this: @RobertHarvey) or they won't get notified when you reply.

Comment: The documentation that I linked explains how to do it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey can you post an example code, which would solve my problem?